# What does 'Font(..)' mean when Font is a class?

Tags: c++

I need help in understanding the following C++ code (in a .h file):

```
bool setFontDescription(const FontDescription& v)
    {
        if (inherited->font.fontDescription() != v) {
            inherited.access()->font = Font(v, inherited->font.letterSpacing(), inherited->font.wordSpacing());
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

What does 'Font(..)' mean? Font is a C++ class. Does Font(...) mean new Font()? Or create a Font object on the stack?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a Font object on stack, as a temporary. The object's scope is the line where it's created.

Answer (score 4):

It means create a Font on the stack, then assign that new Font to the access()->font variable. The Font on the stack is <strike>destroyed when that setFontDescription returns</strike> destroyed when the assignment is done.

Comment: Generally speaking, temporaries are destroyed at the end of the full expression. (A full expression is one that isn't part of some other expression.)